# Is a Spread Unique?

Tags: finite-fields, projective-geometry

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$. It is well known that when $r | n$, there is a set of disjoint $r$-dimensional subspaces of $V$, which covers $V$, called Spread. My question is that is a $r$- dimensional spread in $V$ unique?

Comment: I think you probably meant "trivially intersecting" instead of "disjoint" - all the subspaces intersect at zero. If you act on one Spread by an element of $GL(V)$ you will get another. Thus any $r$-dimensional subspace can be an element of a Spread. It may be (I don't know, need to think!) that a Spread is unique up this action by $GL(V)$. I don't see why it should be so I doubt that's the case, but I don't have a convincing argument. A good question nevertheless (+1).

Comment: @Jyrki many thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is not unique (even up to isomorphism), at least over finite fields. Several examples are known, but the constructions are hard. The classical construction is called the Desarguesian spread. If you google for "non-Desarguesian spread" you will find articles where other constructions are explained.

(Most articles study this in the projective setting, but they are easily convertible.)